# using webpack dev server with css loader

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I have error of http://localhost:8080/images/app.jpg not found error. I suspect it's because css-loader simply ignore the path when I try to do this in my css file

```
.section-a{
    background-color: @red500;
    background-image: url(/images/app.jpg);
    background-position: center;
}
```

I don't have problem in my production config as I don't need to use localhost:8080 as root.

Any clue what else I need to do? I have my css loader config like below

```
{
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
              fallback: 'style-loader',
              use: ['css-loader']
            })
          },
          {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2)$/,
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
          }
```

Comment: you know this says `/images/app.jgp` and not `/images/app.jpg` right?

Comment: What is your publicPath in webpack config?